# -X option not disable sql commands in sqlcmd

Tags: sql-server, sqlcmd

I use sqlcmd to execute large sql file which insert multiple of records into database. So when sqlcmd run it display a error message like **"syntax error near 'Ed'..."** . I known Ed is sql commands and i found -X will disable that kind of commands but it is not work.
My command like this:

```
sqlcmd -S "tcp:ip,1433" -U "sa" -P "pass" -d "dbname" -c "GO" -k 1 -f 65001 -i "C:\sql.sql" -X -x
```

My sql file content:

```
Go
insert into tablename (title) values (N'title 
Ed some more data
some more data
some more data')
Go
insert into tablename (title) values (N'title 
Ed some more data
some more data
some more data')
Go
```

Could you give me some help? please.

Thanks you.

Comment: not sure about sqlcmd use, but what happens if you remove the carriage returns in the string, so you just insert: `values (N'title')`. Perhaps try that so you can make sure that isn't the issue.

Comment: thank you for the suggestion, so i did (remove the "Ed" word) and it is working fine. I just wanna know how to bypass that error. Thanks.

Comment: You can use `N'title '+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'Ed some more data'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'some more data'+CHAR(13)+CHAR(10)+'some more data')`. `CHAR(10)` - Line feed (\n), `CHAR(13)` - Carriage Return (\r).

Answer (score -1):

It use -X[1] instead of -X.

```
   sqlcmd -S "tcp:ip,1433" -U "sa" -P "pass" -d "dbname" -c "GO" -k 1 -f 65001 -i "C:\sql.sql" -X[1]
```

Comment: 1. Not even correct syntax on -X[1]. Correct syntax would be -X 1. This will yield message "Sqlcmd: '[1]': Unexpected argument. Argument value has to be one."

2.  This does not bypass the error. This actually makes the error fatal instead of displaying a message and continuing.